# How to get jquery variable values into php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting some values from html ul elements like this

```
function myFunction() {
    var values =[];
    $('#sortable2').each(function(){ // id of ul
        var li = $(this).find('li')//get each li in ul
        var res = li.text().split("::");
        console.log(res)//get text of each li
    })
}
```

Now I want to get the res values in php variables I am trying this but it is not working

```
function myFunction() {
    var values =[];
    $('#sortable2').each(function(){ // id of ul
        var li = $(this).find('li')//get each li in ul
        var res = li.text().split("::");
        <?php
            $arr = res;
            echo "alert('$arr')";
        ?>
        console.log(res) //get text of each li
    })
}
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: To send variables from JS to PHP you need to use AJAX.

Comment: php runs at server and js runs at browser, very late.....! so either use ajax or submit a form.